# unable to print the arrays

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I wanna store at most 10 numbers but  after I ran the programe, I couldn't print the name and the sentence of "The system is full!!" when the numbers exceed 10. How can I correct it?

```
public static void saveContact(String name, int number) {

     nameRec[nameCounter]= name;
     nameCounter++;

     boolean full = false;
     int i = 0;
     while(i<=9) {
         full = true;
         break;
     }
     i++;

    if(!full) {
        System.out.println("The System is full!!!");
    }else {
    System.out.println("Enter the phone number:");
    }

       System.out.println("Saving the number of\n" + name+ ":" + number);


        }
```

Comment: You are printing "The System is full!!!" when `full` is false. `while(i<=9) {
         full = true;
         break;
     }` doesn't make any sense. `i` is never changed in the loop, and the loop simply immediately breaks after setting `full` to true. So the `while` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: You need to think through your program step by step. What little it does right now is just a jumble.

Comment: Is `nameCounter` a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Variable `i` is never getting incremented inside the while loop. Also where have `namerec` & `nameCounter` been declared. They might be class attributes. If not you have to declare them in a suitable place.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static String[] nameRec = new String[10];
private static int nameCounter;

public static void saveContact(String name, int number) {
    if (nameCounter >= 10) {
        System.out.println("The System is full!!!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Saving the number of\n" + name + ":" + number);
        nameRec[nameCounter++] = name;
    }
}
```

You can build condition just from nameCounter to satisfy your goal.